# How to get NURBS control points from an array of points that should be part of its solution from controll points we are searching for?

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, approximation

We are talking about [Non-uniform rational B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline). We have some simple 3 dimensional array like

```
{1,1,1}
{1,2,3}
{1,3,3}
{2,4,5}
{2,5,6}
{4,4,4}
```

Which are points from a plane created by some B-spline

How to find control points of spline that created that plane? (I know its a hard task because of weights that need to be calculated but I really hope it is solvable)

[image]

Comment: I really do not know tag system on math.stackexchange so feel free to edit tags.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a paper on Object contour extraction using adaptive NURBS VFC active contour: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=5970569&contentType=Conference+Publications

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I realize you don't yet have enough reputation, but this is better as a comment. It can certainly be improved by adding more specific details to answer the OP. Reagrds.